# Null pointer exception error in java button java

Tags: java, user-interface, nullpointerexception, azure-database-mysql

Every time I try to enter the details of email password and name it gives null pointer exception on the button.

However, everything on the database is also valid, and the connection is established too, but it gives error after I press the add accountant button.

I tried to check my database connection code everything is fine, and my connection variable is initialized too.

```
private void addbtn2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

    try {


        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO accountant('email','password','name')VALUES(?,?,?)");

        String names=namef2.getText();
        String emails=emailf2.getText();
        String passwords=String.valueOf(jPasswordField2.getText());
        String c_p=String.valueOf(jPasswordField2.getText());
        stmt.setString(1, emails);
        stmt.setString(2, passwords);
        stmt.setString(3, names);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Accountant Successfully added");
        stmt.execute();
        stmt.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AccountantDetails.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Output

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Admin.panel.AccountantDetails.addbtn2ActionPerformed(AccountantDetails.java:300)
at Admin.panel.AccountantDetails.access$300(AccountantDetails.java:15)
at Admin.panel.AccountantDetails$4.actionPerformed(AccountantDetails.java:186)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 11 seconds)
```

Comment: Try to consequently format your question. Half of your code is plain text...

Answer (score 0):

If this is Button click action

private void addbtn2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

Then parameter should be View not the ActionEvent.

Comment: sir i didn't get you can you give me the whole command if i am mistaken